# USB PD Power Delivery Skip 9V Requirement

Tags: usb, power-delivery

Is there any way possible to implement a USB C PD port that only sources 5V and 15V? As I read the spec (USB Power Delivery Specification Rev. 3.0, Version 1.2, June 21, 2018) it seems that I cannot avoid the 9V requirement. Section 10 page 556.

https://www.usb.org/document-library/usb-power-delivery

Comment: it's almost surely possible, but whether it's standard-compliant is another matter.

Comment: I suppose I should have specified that I wish to remain spec compliant, tho seemed redundant...

Comment: Plenty of people are perfectly fine with non-standard-compliant devices. See the numerous 1A and 2A USB chargers that were on the market before USB officially supported more than 500mA power.

Comment: @Hearth, your example is bad. USB specifications says that a powered host port should supply "at least 5 units of load", which means that supplying more is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Ale..chenski I was under the impression that was added after manufacturers were already making chargers that supplied more than five units, and that before that five units was the maximum. Perhaps I was mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Just shipped a PD product..

If you want compliance then you're going to need 9V. So the question really comes down to do you need the stamp of approval from the USB-IF? Most cases you don't it all depends on what the marketing team thinks is appropriate and is willing to fight for.